# Angular mattooltip overlayElement is null

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I would like to render a mattooltip on an svg drawing.

**component.ts**

```
export class TooltipOverviewExample implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('tooltip') tooltip: MatTooltip;
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    d3.select('svg').on('mouseover', (event) => {
      this.tooltipMessage = 'My tooltip message.';
      this.tooltip.disabled = false;
      this.tooltip.show();

      let tip = this.tooltip._overlayRef.overlayElement; // in my local project this value is empty
      if (tip) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          tip.style.left = 20 + 'px';
          tip.style.top = 40 + 'px';
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

**component.html**

```
<svg>
<g>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="30" height="100" [attr.fill]="fillColor" (click)="changeColor()" />
</g>
</svg>
<div #tooltip="matTooltip" matTooltip={{tooltipMessage}}></div>
```

I'm getting  `null` value on `this.tooltip._overlayRef.overlayElement` => Result : Not able to custom position it

In the [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-fxbok6?file=app%2Ftooltip-overview-example.html) everything is working ok but not in local

I'm not able to know where is the difference.

PS: I'm open to other solutions to show tooltip using an html template reference.

Comment: Can you link a stackblitz that represents what you've tried to do? Make sure your modules, etc. are as close to what is shown in that stackblitz as possible

Comment: I posted a stackblitz example in my post : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-fxbok6?file=app%2Ftooltip-overview-example.html

It's the same as I've done in local for the tooltip

Comment: Wasn't sure if it was your own stackblitz code given the google copy right

Comment: my bad I have forked a repo then edited it